# How does Bootcamp Assistent create a Windows Boot USB?

Tags: usb, boot, bootcamp, assistant

Im trying to reproduce the output of the Bootcamp Assistent, resulting in a bootable Windows USB (Windows 7/8/etc) on a Mac from Terminal.

The USB Stick created by BA (Bootcamp Assistent) works just fine on a Mac and on a PC, but all my tests trying to do it over Terminal resulted in a black screen with a blinking cursor (tested on a native Windows Laptop where the BA USB workes).

I have a original Win 8 iso downloaded directly from Microsoft, so that should not be the problem.

I tried to:

- copy the .iso via dd like: dd if=win.iso of=/dev/rdisk1
- copy the .iso via dd on a FAT32 partition on the USB: dd if=win.iso of=/dev/rdisk1s1
- create a FAT32 partition and copy the content of the .iso to that partition.
- did this: [Create USB stick with Syslinux MBR](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75817/will-bootable-usb-created-by-bootcamp-on-mac-work-with-pc)
- converte the .iso to other formats (eg img) and copyed with dd

The BA USB stick looks like this:

```
/dev/disk1
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.8 GB     disk1
1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              7.8 GB     disk1s1
```

Hopefully someone can tell me what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now i know how Bootcamp Assistent does his magic.. the MBR seems to be bigger than the normal 512 bytes so i did not get the whole thing.. seems to be 7680 bytes long (really dont know why).

But with that extracted mbr i got now it is working as i wanted it to be working.